# Angular promise after calling a service with $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I m actually developping an application with angularjs, and I m facing a problem with $http, and the result of an asynchronous service request to my webservice.

Actually, I m using this code :

```
var promise = undefined;

    UserService.getAll = function (callback) {

        promise = $http({
            url: __ADRS_SRV__ + "users",
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }).success(function(data){
            return data;
        }).error(function(data){
            return $q.reject(data);
        });

        return promise;
    }
```

This doesnt work, and give me some stuff like, I dont know why :

[image: Angular error returned by the call]
To know : in my controller, I want to use a really simple syntax like

```
var data = UserService.getAll();
```

Do you have any idea how should I process to access my data correctly ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: This looks like a job for [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) rather than $http. Additionally, you need to have a look at *callbacks* in Javascript because you're not returning what you think you are returning from inside the `success`/`error` functions

Comment: why you return promise !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get the promise in return. There are multiple ways to use this promise.

**Example 1** (Use promise in service and return reference of an object):

```
UserService.getAll = function () {  
    var dataWrapper = {
        myData: {},
        error: null
    };

    $http({
        url: __ADRS_SRV__ + "users",
        method: "GET",
        isArray: true
    }).success(function(data){
        dataWrapper.myData = data;
    }).error(function(data){
        dataWrapper.error = true;
        return $q.reject(data);
    });

    return dataWrapper;
}
```

**Example 2** (Return promise and use it directly in the controller):

```
// service
UserService.getAll = function () {
    return $http({
        url: __ADRS_SRV__ + "users",
        method: "GET",
        isArray: true
    });
}
// controller
var promise = UserService.getAll();
promise.success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

**Example 3** (Use regular callback):

```
// service
UserService.getAll = function (cb) {
    $http({
        url: __ADRS_SRV__ + "users",
        method: "GET",
        isArray: true
    }).success(cb);
}
// controller
UserService.getAll(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Comment: I ve only tried the last one actually, and it doesn't work because of $scope not accessible in the service

Comment: There are comments to state that this is a part of code in the controller.

Comment: I know that, but the callback will be executed with the service context. And in the service, we dont have $scope defined, so it causes an error "undefined is not a function" :/

Comment: The callback will be called in the promise context, yes. But you get $scope through the closure. Just be sure that you inject $scope into your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The "stuff" you mention is the very promise you create and return.

Comment: So how can I access the data ? :-/

Comment: the way you do it. In the callback function.

Comment: And in my controller ?

Comment: the callback function might be defined in the controller. But you can't have asynchrony without callbacks, and $http is asynchronous.